# Is there a way to implement authentication in Django that requires an API Key and Secret?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, api-key, django-rest-auth

I'm struggling in Django to set up an authentication that uses an API Key and secret. I've tried using the rest_framework_api_key but I don't see a secret offered and the documentation doesn't have very many examples. Does anyone have an example of how you would set this up in Django?

Comment: https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#client-credential

Comment: I tried implementing this but couldn't get it to work. I'm trying to use djangorestframework-api-key as well but I am also struggling with that.